# getting `undefined` parameter error when using a parsed json as javascript object

Tags: javascript, angular6

My `Angular` application receives the following `json`

```
{isSignedIn: true, additional-info: ""{\"external-profile\":{\"email\":\"manu.chadha@ho…\"firstname\":\"Manu\",\"lastname\":\"Chadha\"}}""}
```

I parse the `additional-info` into an object of type `UserProfileAPI`.

```
let resultObject =JSON.parse(subscribed['additional-info']) as UserProfileAPI;

export class UserProfileAPI {
  'external-profile': User;
  constructor(externalProfile:User){
    this['external-profile'] = externalProfile;
  }
}

export class User {
  constructor (public firstname:string,
               public lastname:string,
               public email:string,
               public password:string=""){} 
}
```

My `component` class has a variable `profile:UserProfileAPI;` and I want to mape the values of the received `json` to `profile`.

I have initialized `profile` in `ngOnInit`

```
  this.profile = new UserProfileAPI(new User("","","",""))
```

But when I try to map the `json`

```
let resultObject =JSON.parse(subscribed['additional-info']) as UserProfileAPI;
console.log("parsed additional info is ",resultObject);
this.profile["external-profile"].email = resultObject["external-profile"].email;
this.profile["external-profile"].firstname = resultObject["external-profile"].firstname;
this.profile["external-profile"].lastname = resultObject["external-profile"].lastname;
```

I get error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (nav-component.component.ts:91)
    at`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your example json is not valid json. Are you sure that's what you're getting? as it is not even a valid object :-).

Comment: Thanks. That could be the issue. The server sends `{result: "success", additional-info: "{"external-profile":{"email":"manu.chadha@hotmail.com","firstname":"Manu","lastname":"Chadha"}}"}`. Is the server sending the json in wrong format?

Comment: Thanks to you, The server was sending the result as string. I should have first parsed that string to `json` before assigning it to my model. Without it, I was getting the additional "". So before mapping the incoming data to model, I did `let response: ServerResponseAPI = ev.body;
              console.log("profile in string format is ",response['additional-info']);
              console.log("profile after parsing string to json is ",JSON.parse(response['additional-info']));
              this.profile = JSON.parse(response['additional-info']) as UserProfileAPI;
              `

Comment: happy to accept your comment as answer

Comment: Nah because it's not really an answer. I'd just close it as not many people will be helped by "its a typo".